# Extra url paths as variable

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I have this WordPress pretty permalinks structure:

https://example.com/house/name (where house define post_type)

I want this one url:

https://example.com/house/name/2/3 (that works like https://example.com/house/name, and parse 2 as "nights" variable and 3 like "people" variable). Is this possible?

I have search but not found any similar question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make WordPress aware of custom query string variables using `add_rewrite_tag` in combination with `add_rewrite_rule` https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Comment: @freejack I've tried `add_rewrite_rule` unsuccessfully. `add_rewrite_rule('house/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&nights=$matches[2]&people=$matches[3]', 'top');`. I've flushed rewrite rules, update permalinks but not working :(

Comment: try this rule `add_rewrite_rule('house/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&nights=$matches[2]&people=$matches[3]', 'top');`. Also remember to use `add_rewrite_tag`to add the nights and people tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to register the rewrite rule and rewrite tag for your case is:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%nights%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%people%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('house/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?house=$matches[1]&nights=$matches[2]&people=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

The code has been tested and works correctly.

Comment: Yas! You did it! Thank you a lot :)